# Find optimal orthonormal transformation of functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, rigid-transformation

Let $f,g$ be smooth and integrable functions from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  Can someone help with mentioning some papers that tell me how to find the optimal rigid transformation $O^*$ such that
\begin{align*}
O^* = \arg\max_{O: O^TO=I} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(O x)g(x)\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
Here I wished the assumptions on $f$ and $g$ to be as few and as weak as possible.

Thanks much!

Comment: Optimal in what way?

Comment: If you excuse my ignorance, your integral is a real value.  The maximum of those real values over $O$ (which presumably runs through all "rigid transformations") is also a real value.  How does one take the "arg" of a real value and get a rigid transformation (which is presumably some sort of isometry of $\Bbb{R}^d$)?

Comment: @FruitfulApproach Optimal in the sense that maximizes that product integral

Comment: @ForgotALot Oh sorry... Thanks for the reminder.  I have modified the formulation...  I meant to ask about an optimal **rigid** transformation.